# zipcode/postcode to latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode

How does one convert a zip, or in my case a postal code(UK) to lat long coordinates?

I read upon using google geocoding api but read that is has a fair amount of restrictions such as using google maps in the application and limit to requests.

I also found [this](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/) but I'm not to sure how to go about implementing it

Comment: This tutorial helped me: <http://mhorga.org/2015/08/14/geocoding-in-ios.html>

Comment: "Sorry, we can’t seem to find this page’s pixylls."

Comment: actually it works, the '>' at the end broke the link.  Will have a look, thanks

Answer (score 6):

You would want to use the GeocodeAddressDictionary which accepts a dictionary of specific address types.

In your case, you would do the following.

```
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let dic = [NSTextCheckingZIPKey: yourZipCode]

    geocoder.geocodeAddressDictionary(dic) { (placemark, error) in

        if((error) != nil){
            print(error!)
        }
        if let placemark = placemark?.first {
            let lat = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
            let long = placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude                

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With this code you can do it providing the address (Will be more accurate because a zip code is not a concrete coordinate but an address it is).

Remember to `import CoreLocation` at the top of the class.

```
let address = "1 Infinite Loop, CA, USA"
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
    if((error) != nil){
        print("Error", error)
    }
    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
        let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
    }
})
```